# Is it good way to change one item's values on clicks using getElementById in react item's list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, input

```
class Filter extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           follow: "Follow",
           userList: {
               user1: "A", 
               user2: "B",
               user3: "C", 
               user4: "D",
               user5: "E", 
               user6: "F",
           },
        }
     }

     folowButtonClick = (e) => {
       const taget = document.getElementById(e.target.id);
       target.innerHTML = "Following";
     } 

     render() {
        return this.state.userList.map((user, index, users) (
            <div className="user-container"  key={user.index}>
               <button onClick= 
                   {(e)=>this.folowButtonClick(e)} id={user.index}>Follow
               </button>
            </div>
        )
}}
```

What I'm doing here is rendering list item, and clicking on one DOM Item and changing its content using getElementById.

I think it's not a good way to change any content in this way in React.

I googled it so many time's and not found any way to do this.
I know this is so simple, but I stuck here.

Comment: no , because you shitting over react's virtual dom Reconciliation process , consider saving the value on state of that component or parent component and update the item based on state!!!!

Comment: Hey, Buddy Thanks for the reply. Yeah is not a react way to do it. But how can I change only that clicked item state if I don't have any state like this.  I just want to change clicked item text which is in state.

Comment: He is right, that's not the react way to do it.
I share the code for u @SunilKumar

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do kills the whole purpose of react,
use this approach instead.

But I don't get what you are after, but basically it is what u told me.

```
class Filter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text:'Follow',
            userList: [{
                id: 0
            }, {
                id: 1
            }, {
                id: 2
            }]
        }
        this.folowButtonClick = this.folowButtonClick.bind(this);
    }

    folowButtonClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let state = this.state;
        state.text='Following';
        this.setState({ state });
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.userList.map((user, index)(
            <div className="user-container" key={index}>
                <button onClick=
                    {(e) => this.folowButtonClick(e)}>{this.state.text}
                </button>
            </div>
        )
}
}
```

Comment: Hey Devia, List is coming from some API,  and  might be too big. Another thins is  i don't want to put any extra field in my list(You said put text in all field). I think to put  
a extra  field in all item. It might be a solution , but is there any other way to do this

Comment: No need to send the event here, or invoke prevent default. If it were an anchor tag, and you didn't want it to link somewhere, then yeah, but in this case you can just pass the id.

Comment: You just want to change a text in all these buttons? Am i get it right ?

Comment: Yeah, I also want change classname as well with changing text from Follow to Following

Comment: Updated the answer for u. Hope it helps u.

Comment: Preventing the default behavior is just a best practice which i intend to do every time.

Comment: Hey jsDevia it's it's updating  Following text in every button.

Comment: my first answer gave u a unique text for every button, but u told me you dont want to have this for every button, so i  changed my code to use just one text for every button.
I think i don't get what it is exactly u want.

Comment: https://codepen.io/TheEnd/pen/QVLXYo?editors=0010   @jackquarry from frontend developer slack. this is write buddy